# Number of solutions of the equation $e^{f(x)}=f(x)+2$

Tags: functional-equations

Let $f$ be an everywhere differentiable function, and suppose that $f(x)=0$ has a unique solution, and suppose that $f$ has no local extreme points.

What is the **number** of solutions of the equation 
$$
e^{f(x)}=f(x)+2.
$$
Thanks!

Comment: It is $$f(x)=-W\left(-\frac{1}{e^2}\right)-2$$

Comment: Or $$f(x)=-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{e^2}\right)-2$$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand from where W come from? Is it possible to prove that there are two solutions without using that W function?

Comment: I think it is the LambertW-function

Comment: I think no, there are no solutions which can be expressed by the known elementary functions.

Comment: Yes, but I asked about the **number** of solutions, not the solutions them self

Comment: There are two solutions.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That is not correct, as there are not necessarily values of $x$ satisfying the two equations you wrote. There are either zero, one, or two solutions depending on the function $f(x)$.

Comment: @AjayMishra I'm not sure what you're getting at. If $f(x)=x$, then there are two solutions to $e^{f(x)}=f(x)+2$, i.e., $e^x=x+2$. But I already stated in my comment that one solution is possible for certain choices of $f(x)$, for instance $f(x)=e^x-1$.

Comment: @kccu, why it is not possible to have more than 2 solutions?

Comment: @boaz See my answer.

Comment: Is $e^{f(x)}=f(x)+2$ supposed to hold for all $x$? Is $f(x)$ real or complex function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was noted in the comments, $x$ satisfies $e^{f(x)}=f(x)+2$ if and only if $f(x)=-W\left(-\frac{1}{e^2}\right)-2$ or $f(x)=-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{e^2}\right)-2$, where $W$ and $W_{-1}$ are two branches of the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Importantly, one of these values is positive and one of them is negative (they are about $1.4619$ and $-1.84141$ according to Wolfram Alpha).

So the question becomes: how many solutions can there be to $f(x)=1.4619$ and $f(x)=-1.84141$. Now use the fact that $f$ is differentiable everywhere and has no local extrema to prove that either $f$ is strictly increasing or $f$ is strictly decreasing. Now show that a strictly increasing or strictly decreasing function with a unique solution to $f(x)=0$ can take on any given $y$-value at most once. This proves that there are at most two solutions. You can easily come up with examples of $f(x)$ that take on both values, only one value, or neither value.